# Certificates order in CertPath

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I have 3 certs - Root CA [A], Intermediate CA [B] and some certificate signed by B [C]. I would like to validate C in java. I have CRL and OCSP disabled at them moment. java uses PKIXCertPathValidator implementation for validation under the hood.

I tried two approaches:

1. Pass B and C in CertPath and A as trusted anchor.
2. Pass C in CertPath, A as trusted anchor and B as a CertStore.

Neither approach works. The problem is validator takes element at index 0 form CertPath and then looks for trusted anchor for it. C is signed by B which is not trusted anchor so it fails.

I would like it to work it like:

1. Specify certificate you want to validate.
2. Specify trusted anchor.
3. Provide a bunch of certs that MIGHT be Intermediate CA.
4. Validate certificate.

Comment: Please, show your oode

Comment: If you have all your certificates can't you load them and verify using `X509Certificate::verify` method in a loop?

Comment: What would be the output? You want to know which certificate out of anchors signed  the certificate you want to verify or you just want to know that any certificate validates your certificate?

Comment: I want to know can I reach trust anchor from given cert using given set of intermeduate certs. I expect yes-no answer.

Comment: Ok, that answer is yes.

Comment: :)  let me rephrase it. I want my code to be able to answer this question for different input data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want something like this method :

```
public static boolean verify(X509Certificate certificateToValidate, List<X509Certificate> potentialCAs, X509Certificate root) {
    for(X509Certificate potentialCa : potentialCAs) {
        try {
            certificateToValidate.verify(potentialCa.getPublicKey());
            potentialCa.verify(root.getPublicKey());
            return true; // there was CA that signed you cert and this ca is signed by root
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //not valid
        }
    }

    return false; // validation failed
}
```

You just loop through your potential CAs and check if this CA signs your cert, if yes you check if root signed this CA.

Comment: Ok, so isn't there some more automagic way to get what I want to achieve? If chain is longer then I would be forced to loop through all certs for each intemediate CA.

Comment: You wrote that you have three certs so I assumed you have three "levels" of certificates chain. I am not aware of different solution because in this scenario you would have to validate each possible combination of certificates at different level of the chain.

Comment: So basically I can verify if chain reaches trust anchor only if chain is ordered, right?